# REST API Validation Layer

Tags: validation, rest

I would like to implement a RESTful API in order to give clients access to our internal services.

Regarding API validation, I have two approaches in mind:

- Use external validation layer which would cover the areas exposed by the resources.
- Use internal business logic validators and just capture the internal exceptions and errors and convert into API friendly exceptions.

I'm personally in favour of the first approach, but due to potential code duplication for validating properties, I was suggested the second approach, which I find kind of messy and unnecessary.
I don't want to give access to very low level logic if the request params are not valid in the first place, for example.

Which approach is more appropriate? Any best practices?

Comment: Where are you implementing the external validation layer? Server-side? How does it sit over the API? Best practice is for a module to perform validation on any data coming into it before using it. Unless your external validation layer is still deployed in the same module as the API, you're vulnerable to them becoming decoupled and users avoiding the layer.

Comment: The external validation layer would be in the same platform as the API and it is server side. The validation would be done in any case, the difference is that it will either take place before the business objects (services) use it (and probably validate it as they need it) or in a separate validation layer before it even get to the business objects. The latter would be a very specific interface as xsd was to xml for incoming requests.